# Unable to symbolicate Xamarin Forms iOS crashes - 'No symbolic information found'

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, testflight, symbolicatecrash

After studying a large number of posts on this topic I'm still unable to symbolicate my Xamarin Forms iOS crashes from TestFlight. In the final step below, I get:

```
Num stacks found:17
0 binary images remain after pruning
0 binary images were found
No symbolic information found.
```

My steps:

1. After building the app I saved away the .app file from bin/iPhone/Release/.
2. When uploading to App Store Connect, ticked the boxes to upload symbols.
3. In Xcode 11.4.1, drilled down into my build's archive at Organizer/Archives to get the .dSYM file. (Clicking on Download Debug Symbols resulted in 'No dSYMs were found for version xxx.)
4. On the Crashes tab, drilled down on my build and retrieved *.crash files.
5. Assembled the above files in a folder Desktop/CrashFiles.
6. In Terminal, entered the following:

   export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

   alias symbolicate="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v"

   cd Desktop/CrashFiles

   symbolicate -o "symbolicatedCrash.txt" "xyz.crash" "MyApp.iOS.app"

UPDATE: Using dwarfdump I verified that .app, .dSYM and .crash all have the same UUID. Also, I've done nothing to include bitcode.

The app uses .NET Standard 2.0 with a library that is also .NET Standard 2.0.

Would very much appreciate suggestions. I am on the Community Edition of Visual Studio and don't have HockeyApp.

Version info:

Xcode V11.4,
  Xamarin.iOS V13.16,
  Xamarin.Forms V4.6,
  Visual Studio for Mac V8.5.5

Some of the posts I've seen are:

- [How to symbolicate crash/error logs from a Xamarin Forms iOS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579117/how-to-symbolicate-crash-error-logs-from-a-xamarin-forms-ios-project)
- https://jmillerdev.com/symbolicating-ios-crash-files-xamarin-ios/
- [How to symbolicate crash report from Apple received in .txt format not .crash format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479835/how-to-symbolicate-crash-report-from-apple-received-in-txt-format-not-crash-fo/45207863)
- [Strange errors when attempting to Symbolicate iOS crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676044/strange-errors-when-attempting-to-symbolicate-ios-crash-report)
- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69919/from-xcode-how-open-an-app-store-crash-log-in-xamarin-studio
- [Xcode - There are no dSYMs available for download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159244/xcode-there-are-no-dsyms-available-for-download)

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of the Terminal commands. Here they are one by one:

Comment: export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

Comment: alias symbolicate="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v"

Comment: cd Desktop/CrashFiles

Comment: symbolicate -o "symbolicatedCrash.txt" "xyz.crash" "MyApp.iOS.app"

Comment: Two great ideas I'll try when I can: In Build>Compiler options for solution and iOS project, set Debug information to Full; disable in-app crash handling code. From Rolf's comments at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10704/releasing-app-with-debug-symbols