# iOS 13 TestFlight not reporting crash, only feedback.json

Tags: ios, testflight, crash-reports, ios13

With the new feature of iOS 13 to report crashes for TestFlight builds, on some apps I have a problem that only `feedback.json` is reported without actual crash report.
Is there anything to enable?

Worth to mention that crashalitics is enabled and not reporting any of the crash.

**Update:** so after some investigation, I found that `reports without a crash logs are system terminations`. In my case when I extracted device logs from the phone and it was `0xbadf000d`, one of the meanings is system terminated a long process in the background. Seems it was always there, but with iOS13 Testflight feedback it becomes visible with popups.

By the wat, somehow logs from Xcode "Devices and simulators" are not in sync with logs directly on the phone.

**Takeaway:** Faced a need to manually simbolicate a crash report, so found super useful stackoferlow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207863/3032917

Comment: i got the same issue. i . am getting crash popup message. but no crash logs available.

Comment: Hey. Did you resolve the problem ?

Comment: Same here, is there any ideas?

Comment: same problem.. any updates on this?

Answer (score 8):

This happens when the watchdog kills the application due to some reason. we can check the logs in the Analytic & Improvement section

Comment: You saved my day! Detailed instructions on obtaining logs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/acquiring-crash-reports-and-diagnostic-logs, Logs on device section.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue, the system terminates the network extension due to some reason. And, many users has downloaded the app from test-flight and they are seeing the default crash alert from OS. since test-flight feedback does't contain crash logs, i am not able to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same behaviour when the specific device was on low storage. The device has less than 50 MB remaining from 30GB of storage.

Comment: Mine had 64GB available but still no crash report.

Answer (score -5):

You mixed up the crash log and crash feedback of TestFlight.

What you see in JSON format is Crash Feedback. It is available since iOS 13 devices and can be obtained by App Store Connect > TestFlight.

For Crash Log, it can be found in Xcode > Organizer > Crashes. If you cannot see the logs, it will appear few hours later (but please make sure dSYM is enabled when you're uploading the archive to the App Store Connect).

Comment: Normally crash feedback is provided with feedback.json and crash log attached. But what I am searching for is why there are crash feedbacks, but no crash logs attached. 
Crashes which are in Xcode > Organizer > Crashes show only crashes which are the same which you can find in TestFlights crash feedbacks. But only if there is feedback.json + crash log.