# Why do crash reports in App Store Connect sometimes not provide the crash file?

Tags: app-store-connect

Our app gets crash reports from TestFlight users and those get sent to the `Crash Feedback` page of App Store Connect. Usually, when you download the crash feedback, we are provided a `feedback.json` file, which contains some metadata, and a `crashlog.crash` file which contains a symbolicated crash file. However, occasionally, when downloading the feedback, App Store Connect will *only* provide us with the `feedback.json` file and **no crashlog file**.

I've tried signing out and in and deleting cookies from that site, thinking maybe I'd gotten into a weird state.  So far, none of those things have worked. Some coworkers have reported that they've been able to refresh the page a few times and get it to provide all the files, but I haven't been successful with that personally.

It's unclear if this is something the user has to opt into, or if it's something on my end that I need to do (or maybe it's just a transient error?). Has anyone else experienced this, or have any idea what may be happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 13 TestFlight not reporting crash, only feedback.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58412774/ios-13-testflight-not-reporting-crash-only-feedback-json)

Comment: @LukeVo no it doesn't