# TestFlight not providing crash log

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight

For a certain crash I am only getting TestFlight feedback and not the crash log. Meaning I cannot open the crash in Xcode to figure out what the issue is. Is there a reason for this?

How can I get the crash log?

Comment: I think this is a dupe of my own question. Unfortunately, I never got a solution. My guess is it's an Apple bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755313/why-do-crash-reports-in-app-store-connect-sometimes-not-provide-the-crash-file

Comment: Have you tried searching for the crash in the Organizer window in Xcode?

Comment: @Frederik the Organizer is not showing all the crashes. One of my user report a crash, it's on the feedback page of app store connect but not in the crash list of XCode.