# No crash report version in mycrash.crash

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, app-store-connect

I sent application to Appstoreconnect and its rejected for a crash. I try to symbolicate to this crash and follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207863/9110909) answer.

I created all the necessary things and my Folder looks like
[image]

symbolicatecrash scripts from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/`

When I go this directory on terminal and run these :

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
./symbolicatecrash mycrash.crash > symbolicated.crash
```

I'm getting this error message :

```
No crash report version in mycrash.crash at ./symbolicatecrash line 1365.
```

How can I fix this issue? Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Same issue. :( Did you find a solution?

Comment: No , still exist @johnelemans

Comment: I got this one to work yesterday;  https://gist.github.com/bmatcuk/c55a0dd4f8775a3a2c5a

Comment: We have same issue, can you tell please did you find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately, couldn't find any solution . But when I asked them to please give details to Apple's support message on the subject, they took a screenshot telling me at what stage the error was.  @Petr

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the issue as well when using symbolicatecrash on a file generated from an ips crash file using a script (https://github.com/tomieq/AppleCrashScripts?ref=iosexample.com). Resolved it by adding

Report Version:      104

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell please in which part of crash we need to add "Report Version: 104"? I tried to add it in different places and this didnt work.

Comment: Sure. it needs to go right to the top section e.g.
Process: .. 
Path:..
Identifier:...
Version:
...
Report Version: 104
...
Release Type ....

Comment: In case your crash is an .ips file, you might be able to convert it to a ".crash" file using this tool: https://github.com/tomieq/AppleCrashScripts?ref=iosexample.com.  and it will add a report version  number to it. After that you can run it through the ./symbolicatecrash tool